# .Net Framework version dll compatibility

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version

I have a project in .Net Framework 4.5 but I got a third party dll which is in .Net Framework version 4.5.2. It does not support on 4.5 version. Could it be possible that I run that dll on 4.5 version.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Pretty sure not. The code is downward, not upward compatible. It is "the highest required Framework". Of course that begs the question: Why not just change the Project to target 4.5.2? Are any limitations of the Framework version in place? The change itself would be relatively speaking trivial.

Comment: I have a project which consists of 106 projects If I change the .Net Framework version. It means I need to change in the 106 projects and there could be a consequences. It takes a time to do it. The problem is that I have to deploy corrections on production as soon as possible

Comment: You can effortlessly reference 1.1 compiled Code in a 4.5.2 Project. The other way around, that is where issues lie. And the amount of differences in version numbers does not even mater. There are actually peices of the codebase that have not changed their IL representation a single bit since then. TryParse, CrossThreadExceptions and INotifyPropertyChanged are old 2.0 additions and they are widly used to this day.

Answer (score 0):

No, don't think you can reference that dll since it's target framework version `4.5.2` is higher than the version your referencing project is built on.

> I have a project in .Net Framework 4.5

You can change the target framework version for this project to `4.5.2` as well to be compatible.

Comment: I have a project which consists of 106 projects If I change the .Net Framework version. It means I need to change in the 106 projects and there could be a consequences. It takes a time to do it. The problem is that I have to deploy corrections on production as soon as possible.